# Detectar si existe algún tipo de IE (Internet Explorer)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ecmascript-6, internet-explorer, emacs

¿Como puedo detectar mediante `javascript` que tipo de navegador esta usando el usuario?. Esta pregunta es dada en base a que existe una aplicación que no corre en ninguna versión de `IE` y para ello es necesario notificar al usuario con un mensaje para humanos.

En Internet encontré muchas formas que al parecer para esta altura del tiempo ya son obsoletas, dado que Microsoft cambia anualmente o cada una nueva versión su metadata de `navigator`. Por esto es que abro esta pregunta. ¿Existirá una nueva forma para poder realizar esto?

Las siguiente formas probadas, al parecer están **DEPRECATED**

```
navigator.appName === 'Microsoft Internet Explorer'


navigator.userAgent.match(/MSIE/g)


navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE")
```

Estuve revisando la metadata que devolvía `navigator` en navegadores como Chrome, Firefox y Edge en donde pude observar que en el `navigator.appName` todos comparten el mismo nombre `Netscape` inclusive IE. Pude apreciar que para el `navigator.userAgent` todos tienen metadata diferente inclusive IE, pero existe una key dentro de ella que es `Trident` que solo esta presente en IE, sera correcto usar esto...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, usar `window.navigator.userAgent` es la mejor manera.

Tienes que agregar más lógica para las diferentes versiones, no vienen todas bajo un mismo nombre.

Aquí un ejemplo que encontré en codepen:

https://codepen.io/gapcode/pen/vEJNZN

Fragmento:

```
  var msie = ua.indexOf('MSIE ');
  if (msie > 0) {
    // IE 10 or older => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf('.', msie)), 10);
  }

  var trident = ua.indexOf('Trident/');
  if (trident > 0) {
    // IE 11 => return version number
    var rv = ua.indexOf('rv:');
    return parseInt(ua.substring(rv + 3, ua.indexOf('.', rv)), 10);
  }

  var edge = ua.indexOf('Edge/');
  if (edge > 0) {
    // Edge (IE 12+) => return version number
    return parseInt(ua.substring(edge + 5, ua.indexOf('.', edge)), 10);
  }
```

***EDIT***

Aquí esta la lista completa de user agent strings para IE

http://useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php?name=Internet+Explorer

Como puedes ver es bastante larga por lo cual quizá necesitas otra manera.

Otra opción es validar positivos (los navegadores que **si** soportas) y mostrarle un mensaje permanente al usuario diciendo "No soportamos IE"

Este mensaje le aparecería solamente a los usuarios de IE

```
if not ( Chrome or FF or Safari or Opera) then
    show "No soportamos IE (o lo que sea que estes usando)"
end
```

Comment: Es la misma forma que tuve que usar, usando el string Trident, ¿pero sera la mejor? ya que como lo indicas a parte se debe validar cada versión de IE que existe o de lo contrario omitir el versionado y solo validar por Trident entendiendo que si existe este string estamos hablando de alguna versión de IE, ahora no se si todas las versiones de IE tienen esta cadena en su userAgent

Comment: Iba a hacer un comentario pequeño, pero mejor terminé editando la respuesta original. TLDR; también puedes validar los navegadores que sí soportas.